# If $R$ is a commutative ring with unit element, then $R$ has a maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

There is a theorem we stated during lectures and referred to it as "Kronecker's theorem". The theorem claims what is written in the title above, but proof to the theorem was messy, and I cannot find it anywhere. The proof looked something like this, and is based on Zorn's lemma: Let  $(I_t)_{t \in T}$ is set of all proper ideals in $R$. It is inductively ordered set relative to inclusion (I do not know why this is true). For any two $t_1 \ne t_2$ is $I_{t_1} \subset I_{t_2}$ or $I_{t_2} \subset I_{t_1}$ $(1)$. Let $I = \bigcup\limits_{t \in T} I_t$. Let us prove $I$ is ideal in $R$. Let $x, y \in I$, then $x \in I_{t_1}$ and $y \in I_{t_2}$; so because of $(1)$ we get, without loss of generality, that $x, y \in I_{t_1}$ (for instance). But $I_{t_1}$ is ideal in $R$, so $x - y, xr \in I_{t_1}$, for any $r \in R$ and hence $I_{t_1} \subset I$, we obtain that $I$ is ideal in $R$. It is obvious that $I \ne R$, because $(I_t)_{t \in T}$ is family of proper ideals, so $1 \notin I_{t}, \forall t \in T$, which implies that $1 \notin I = \bigcup\limits_{t \in T} I_t$. Now, by applying Zorn's lemma on $I$ we get the claim of the theorem. I am confused about the claim that the family of the proper ideals is inductively ordered. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you stating that any two proper ideals are contained one in the other? Because that's not true, but you need only a partial order

Comment: I am not sure. This is a theorem we claimed during lectures on class Abstract algebra, and the theorem should be on exam in two days... But, I am stuck with it, because I don't comprehend it. Do you know any other proof to this theorem. Anything is helpful.

Comment: I think this is the simpler proof. As Bernard said, you probably misunderstood Zorn's lemma. The set of ideals is partially ordered by the inclusion, to apply Zorn you have to show that every ascending chain of ideals is contained in an ideal, which is given by the union of all the terms

Comment: So only thing that I need to change in the proof is the claim that of ideals is totally ordered, and instead of that write partially order?

Comment: Yes, but you have to make clear that when you define $I$ in your proof you are considering and ascending chains of ideal, which is indeed totally ordered

Comment: I hadn't realised this was known by Kronecker's name. I don't think he would be pleased to have such a nonconstructive result named after him!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply misunderstood what *Zorn's lemma* asserts: it says that if in a  `partially ordered`  set, every `totally ordered subset` has an upperbound, then the partially  ordered set has maximal elements.

So here , what is checked if that any `totally ordered`  family of ideals has an upper bound (which is, of course their union). This does not mean *any* family of ideals is totally ordered.

Comment: I am still confused.So, what should I change in the proof, because as far as I get from your comment the proof is correct, just my claims are not?

Comment: You seem to have understood the proof, except you thought it was asserted that   ideals were linearly ordered, whereas one says (perhaps not as explicitly as the way I formulate it): ‘Consider a linearly ordered family of ideals’.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it now: "It is inductively ordered set relative to inclusion...", should be omitted.